# hibernate + named query not known

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting problem while using named query with hibernate and spring.

below is my code and stacktrace.

Method that is calling my query is :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<CampaignEntity> getCampaignList() {     
        final Query clientQuery = getNamedQuery(CampaignEntity.GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY);
        return (List<CampaignEntity>) clientQuery.list();
    }
```

my Entity class is

```
package com.nativeunlock.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = CampaignEntity.GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY,
            query = "from CampaignEntity campaign"
    )     
})

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "campaign")
public class CampaignEntity implements Serializable {

    public static final String GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY ="getCampaignList";

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "campaingn_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int campain_id;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "no_of_views")   
    private int no_of_views;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "video_url") 
    private int video_url;      

}
```

my xml file is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nativeunlock.**" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:common.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="${datasource.class}">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.nativeunlock.dao.**"/>       
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="targetUrl" />
    </bean>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <security:global-method-security
        jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"
        secured-annotations="enabled" />

</beans>
```

my stacktrace is

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: getCampaignList
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSess
ionImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:137
1)
        at com.nativeunlock.dao.CampaignDao.getNamedQuery(CampaignDao.java:41)
        at com.nativeunlock.dao.CampaignDao.getCampaignList(CampaignDao.java:47)

        at com.nativeunlock.service.CampaignService.getCampaignList(CampaignServ
ice.java:20)
        at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginCo
ntroller.java:31)
        at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController$$FastClassByCGLI
B$$25d5f75b.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocatio
n.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecur
ityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterc
eptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
        at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController$$EnhancerByCGLIB
$$ac304978_2.campaign(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.
invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandle
rAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandle
rAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl
et.java:778)
```

Can any one help me to find out what wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not scanning the package where you're named query resides, you scan `com.nativeunlock.dao.**`

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.nativeunlock.dao.**"/>
```

and you're entity is within `com.nativeunlock.dto`

Comment: I have check that one also but getting same error:(

Comment: @AnupamSharma just try with this `<context:component-scan base-package="com.nativeunlock" />`.
Also remove `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.nativeunlock.dao.**"/>  ` from `sessionFactory`